# String - why there are there different return values in both the cases?

Tags: java

Why there is a different output for String and String buffer?

```
public class ReturnValueFromTryCatchFinally {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(methodReturningValue());
    }

    static StringBuffer methodReturningValue() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            buffer.append("aa");
            return buffer;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            buffer.append("bbb");
            return buffer;
        }
        finally {
            buffer.append("vvvv");
        }
        
    }
    
    static String methodReturningValue1() {
        String buffer = new String();
        try {
            buffer=buffer.concat("aa");
            return buffer;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            buffer=buffer.concat("bbb");
            return buffer;
        }
        finally {
            buffer=buffer.concat("vvvv");
        }
        
    }

}
```

For User defined object, it is also behaves same as String.

Comment: `return` in the `catch` is called before the `finally` clause is executed. So you can't change the reference of the `String` and expect to return it.

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` block gets invoked *after* the value of `buffer` is read in `return buffer;`. Any changes to the variable `buffer` itself are not returned.

In the case where `buffer` is a StringBuffer, you are not changing the value of `buffer`, but instead you are changing the *content* of `buffer`, and that can be seen by the caller of the method.

But in the case where `buffer` is a String, you cannot do the same. String is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

When the finally block performs `buffer=buffer.concat("vvvv");`, it assigns a new `String` to the local variable `buffer`, but the method returns the original `String` instance that was referenced by `buffer` when the `return buffer;` statement was evaluated.

When the finally block performs `buffer.append("vvvv")`, it mutates the same instance that is returned in the `return buffer` statement, so you see the mutated instance returned from the method.

The behavior of the first method is equivalent to:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("aa");
StringBuffer returned = buffer;
buffer.append("vvvv"); // mutates the same instance that will be returned
return returned;
```

The behavior of the second method is equivalent to:

```
String buffer = new String();
buffer=buffer.concat("aa");
String returned = buffer;
buffer=buffer.concat("vvvv"); // doesn't affect the returned instance
return returned;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return buffer;` remembers instance to return. `buffer=buffer.concat("vvvv")` create new instance of string, but it never used.

Answer (score 0):

In StringBuffer case it implicitly knows the reference of the object when object value got changed in finally block it understood automatically.
But in case of String you are pointing to the reference and then concatenating the String, because String is immutable.